# ace:dataTable single and double click row selection listener

Tags: row, selection, icefaces-3, ace-datatable

Is it possibile to handle in the same ace:dataTable even single click and double click row selection in order to associate them two different behaviors? 
example: I need to open the row detail with double click selection and i need to only select the row with a single click.